# Web service returns same XML data twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I am using web service to get information about an airport using the airport code. 
Here is the result for calling the method `InformationByAirportCode` with parameter value `"MBX"`:
[image: web service airport problem]

Notice how the same tags and values are repeated twice. Here is my code for calling the method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string InformationByAirportCode(string code)
{
     net.webservicex.www.airport AirportService = new net.webservicex.www.airport();
     string airport_info = AirportService.getAirportInformationByAirportCode(code);

     return airport_info;  
}
```

Where is the problem, that I receive same results twice in one XML?

Here is the URL connection to the web service in Web References in Visual Studio 2010, using .NET Framework 3.5 in an ASP.NET Web Service Application.

[image: web references]

Link to the service: http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx

Comment: where do you call this method from?

Comment: @Badiparmagi My own service calls the method

Comment: They just really want to make sure you get the content. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the server, you should check the server code. When you call the service from the internet, you get the result you see in the screenshot you posted.